# Crashlytics generating misleading stack traces in release mode (Android)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, crashlytics, crash-reports

My Android app has Crashlytics all set up and I made a small code to generate a native crash to test the reports. I've followed every setup instruction and I am using the latest Crashlytics version.

When I execute my crash test in debug mode, reports arrive with readable and precise stack traces. However, when I do the same test on the release build of my app, I do get crash reports with readable stack traces but they point to wrong locations in my code.

Coincidentally or not, the misleading traces point to another method that lies right below the actual origin of the crash. I do get file name and lines though, only there's no way the crash could be coming from the source it points to.

The native source is built using regular CMakeLists.txt and is being loaded from another library module that accommodates my native library.

Both debug and release symbols are being uploaded with the following commands:

```
./gradlew app-module:assemblerelease app-module:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFilerelease
./gradlew app-module:assembledebug app-module:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFiledebug
```

Has anyone ever experienced it before? What could be causing these readable but slightly misleading traces only in release mode?

EDIT:

The reason why I believe the trace misplacement is sort of random and non related to inlining or unrolling is because both the actual crash source and the misplaced origin are pretty straight-forward and unrelated. Also there are no calls to `ShowMessage` near the part of the code where `TestCrash` gets called.

```
void ScriptWrapper::TestCrash()
{
    MyObject* obj = nullptr;
    obj->GetID(); // this is where the crash takes place
}

void ScriptWrapper::ShowMessage(std::string sMsg, const MESSAGE_TYPE type, const bool abort)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    Logger::TYPE logType;
    switch (type)
    {
    case ERROR:
        ss << ("ERROR - ");
        logType = Logger::ERROR; // this is where the release crash stack trace points at
        if (abort)
        {
            Abort();
        }
        break;
    case WARNING:
        ss << ("Warning - ");
        logType = Logger::WARNING;
        break;
    default:
        logType = Logger::INFO;
    };
    ss << sMsg;
    Log(ss.str(), logType);
}
```

Comment: Release code will have been optimized by the compiler eg inlining, unrolling, intermediate code removal etc.  Can you post the test code (function) around the crash location?

Comment: plenty of reasons for stack trace to be boggled: call stack could be corrupted, control flow could accidentally fall through and so on.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you very much for your input. I've edited my question in response to it.

Comment: are there any differences on how both versions are being built? like running an  optimization?

Comment: @Gerardo I'm doing this on release: `buildTypes.release.externalNativeBuild.cmake.cppFlags += "-O3 -DNDEBUG"`

Comment: Does it work if you don't use the optimization flag? or a different level of optimization? https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100748/0612/using-common-compiler-options/selecting-optimization-options

Comment: @Gerardo it consistently outputs the same results without optimization flags. I wonder if the NDK sets other flags by default though. In any case, it should behave properly with its default settings. I'll try other versions of the NDK and I'll write back if I find anything relevant.